# Shortcut for not saving document in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, shortcuts

I am using Photoshop in Mac and I know there is a shortcut key for not saving a document, which is Cmd + Shift + '[back] Delete' (the one same as Windows' Backspace), but I cannot find the same shortcut for Illustrator.

Is there possible to set it?

Comment: Just tap the D key on the keyboard when asked if you want to save.

Comment: That would do, thanks! Why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Scott, pressing the D key should do the trick.